# Возможно ли использовать псевдонимы на кириллице в Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

Уместен ли следующий кусок запроса?

```
SELECT ClientName AS 'Имя клиента' FROM ClientTable
```

В разных источниках ответы, которые отличаются. Где-то говорят, что нельзя. Где-то - что можно, но с ограничениями. И всё же утвердительного ответа не получил. Возможно ли в Firebird использовать псевдонимы на кириллице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, все зависит от версии, у меня начиная с версии FB 2.5 работает так:

```sql
SELECT ClientName AS "Имя клиента" FROM ClientTable
/*___________________^___________^________________*/
```

и да ограничение на алиас 31 байт, ~15 символов до версии FB4
На версиях FB 1.5 не работает (dialect 1)
Использовал для проверки IBExpert и спасибо [@VP_ARTH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth) за подсказку: dialect 3

Comment: dialect=3 не забыть ещё)

Comment: Вот оказывается база использует диалект 1. Изменил на третий и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

С разрешения Сергея Астахова, владельца страницы http://people.comita.spb.ru/users/sergeya/java/ruschars.html, приводится часть раздела, описывающая работу с русскими буквами в InterClient:
InterBase (interbase.interclient.Driver)

Для этого драйвера работает параметр "charSet":

```
   // Параметры соединения с базой
   Properties connInfo = new Properties();

   connInfo.put("user", username);
   connInfo.put("password", password);
   connInfo.put("charSet", "Cp1251");

   // Устанавливаем соединение
   Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(dataurl, connInfo);
```

Однако не забудьте при создании БД и таблиц указать кодировку символов. Для русского языка можно использовать значения "UNICODE_FSS" или "WIN1251".